# c# Webservice method multithreading/ParallelProcessing with time

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, unit-testing, parallel-processing

In c# ,how to capture each thread's start time,end time and duration of processing?

I want to simulate webservice concurrency,so that at same time multiple threads(eg 10 threads) calling same webservice.Same time response time of each call needs to be captured.

Tried following but not able to find each thread's start and end time with duration.

```
    foreach (Thread t in pool)
      {t.Start();}
```

or

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, i =>
 { }
```

Comment: For reasons which should be obvious at this point, code should be placed in the *question*, not in a comment.  (And should also include a description of what exactly is failing.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Parallel class for this, clean and easy :

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, i =>
{
    //Call webservice here
});
```

Comment: How about ` Parallel.For(0, 10new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, i =>
            {

                startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var result = proxy.DownloadFile("123");
                endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                duration = endTime - startTime;

Print startTime ,endTime ,duration 
});`